# Best way to get range from 1 to n-1 with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to use linq to query a sorted List with n elements, so that I can get elemnts between first and last.

I have tried the following, but it seems not to look good:

```
var result1 = myList.Skip(1).Take(myList.Count()-2);

var result2 = myList.GetRange(1, myList.Count()-2);
```

Are there other ways to achieve the goal?

Comment: Use [`List.GetRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want best performance. That's not LINQ of course.

Comment: What does "not to look good" mean?

Comment: What is the problem with your attempts?

Comment: They look fine to me. I prefer the first approach though, as I'm used to seeing Skip and Take used for thing like paging.

Comment: I guess "not look good" means that you have to do the "count-2" thing, whereas OP probably expected something similar to Haskell's `init.tail`. However, in C# this is probably the best you can do except defining an extension method to hide the complexity.

Comment: Other way: `var result = myList.Skip(1).Reverse().Skip(1).Reverse();` But.. Very insufficient.

Comment: Right, the  "not look good" was related to the "Count()-2", I was wondering if there is another way. The approach with "Reverse()" seems to be a possibility.

Comment: What is wrong with `Count()-2`? There is no reason this would fail one day (except in multi-threaded environment). BTW, why are you using the `Count` extension method instead of the `Count` list property? (is `myList` not a `List`?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to take into account that LinQ will perform as many loops as necessary to achieve its purpose. Sometimes, writing your own loop will gets better results. Then encapsulate your loop into an extension methods and you get your one line solution:

```
namespace System.Linq
{
    public static class MyLinqExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> Range<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, int start, int end)
        {               
            int i = 0;
            foreach(var item in input)
            {
                if(i < start) continue;
                if(i > end) break;

                yield return item;

                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, this approach looks really promising, like it!

Comment: Seems, we need to move i++; to the beginning of the loop, before first IF statement

Answer (score 1):

This is Best Way

```
 var result1 = myList.Skip(1).Take(myList.Count()-2);
```

This Best way of Linq Query Because Getrange does not accept Negative Numer.

For Example: 
 MyList is No record then Skip And Take method execute Linq query out put is empty list result but Getrange method throw exception for "**Non-negative number required.
Parameter name: count**"

Comment: Thanks for the information about the negative number!